# php получить доступ к методу protected у объекта 2

Tags: php

Есть объект некого класса "A", нужно вывести его свойство и вызвать метод.

php выдает ошибку, что нет доступа к этим методам т.к. они pretected.

как получить доступ?

- Подробнее:

Есть событие

```
function before($obj) { }
```

параметр `$obj` - это объект класса `Events`, у которого есть поле `result` (массив) - `protected`.

нужно в событии получить к нему доступ. Я пытаюсь наследовать:

```
class myClass extends Events { 
    public function A() { 
       print_r($this->result); 
    } 
} 

$q = new myClass; 
$q->A();
```

Естественно выводит пустой результат, т.к. я обращаюсь напрямую к свойству класса не к свойству объекта. Как к объекту обратиться?

Comment: Вы что-то не так делаете. Ибо протектед доступны и наследникам тоже.... лучше бы вы показали еще код класса `Events` и пояснили бы причем тут `before`

Answer (score 3):

**Во-первых**, то что вы делаете - это не правильно. Защищенные свойства должны быть использованы только в текущем классе либо в его наследниках. Это основы ООП и надо с ними считаться. Лучше хорошенько подумать, почти наверняка есть **другой путь** решения проблемы.

**Во-вторых**, наследование в данном случае вам не поможет потому, что объект передаваемый в `before` *уже создан* и является экземпляром `Events`, а не вашего дочернего класса `myClass`.

**В-третьих**, расскажу вам о небольшом расширении PHP о котором мало кто знает (или же люди просто забывают о его существовании), а именно о [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php). Это расширение позволяет творить чудеса. К примеру, получить значения защищенного свойства можно так:

```
function before($obj) {
    $ref = new \ReflectionClass($obj);

    $prop = $ref->getProperty('result');
    $prop->setAccessible(true);

    // А теперь немного магии. Переменная $res после выполнения строчки ниже будет содержать
    // значение защищенного свойства.
    $res = $prop->getValue($obj);
}
```

Этот же трюк работает и для частных (private) свойств.

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу 2 пути:

```
class Events {
    protected $result = array(0, 1, 2);

    public function getResult() {
        return $this->result;
    }
}

class myClass extends Events { 
    public function A() { 
        print_r($this->getResult()); 
    } 

    public function B() {
        print_r($this->result);
    }
} 

$q = new myClass; 
$q->A();
$q->B();
```

Сложности не вижу... Или я не правильно понял вопрос?